# How to create a 3D logo in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, 3d

In [this site](http://thedesigninspiration.com/logos/vision/)  I found one logo which might be made in Adobe Illustrator:

[image: http://maxcdn.thedesigninspiration.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Vision-l.jpg]

It's a perfect 3D logo, how can this kind of logo be made with Illustrator?.

Comment: This isn't a 3D logo, it was drawn. If you look at the right, the angle on the top that it makes is an impossible shape in 3d if you look at the angle from the bottom. The shading is also imperfect from what a 3D rendering would be.

Comment: This question does not show any effort of the OP. Please add what you have tried yourself to the question so it becomes more clear what the problem is.

Comment: This logo was stolen from here without my permission
http://99designs.com/logo-design/contests/logo-software-product-ediflo-47397/entries/98

Comment: Unfortunately i sent mails here to show them that but they never answer me, i think they should remove it because they dont have the permission of the original designer, and the work is on this website.

Comment: this is not a discussion forum. Posting "answers" is not going to change anything. Flag the question for moderator attention instead. The OP could not know that the site he took a screenshot of copied your design. Again: it is not posted as his own work, just as an example he would like to match. I would say it's fair use. But as you consistently keep saying you want it removed you should contact the mod and not waste your time adding answers to which I might comment.

Comment: @grade Actually the image **here** came from [Design Inspiration](http://thedesigninspiration.com/logos/vision/) and is correctly attributed here as fair use. If *they* have stolen it from you, you should take that up with them.

Comment: after more research this logo was uploaded to [Design Inspiration](http://thedesigninspiration.com/logos/vision/) as a revision to the original referenced link so the original reference was incorrect and at the time couldn't be found.  After further review the links were corrected and the logo was loaded by [Brand Mango](http://www.brandmango.com/) to a public site and the issue should be discussed with Brand Mango.

Answer (score 3):

Adobe Illustrator isn't a 3D rendering program, so to create anything 3D in Illustrator requires that you simply draw it to look 3D.

How to draw something in 3D really isn't a topic specific to any particular drawing software, you just have to understanding some fundamentals of drawing...things like shading, color, shadows, gradients, highlights, etc.

Comment: Your best bet is to place the picture into illustrator and then use the pen tool to outline all the edges. You can then sample the colors and create the gradients pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good in illustrator, but I believe you can. I just drew an image almost the same as the one above using illustrator to prove that it's possible.

[image: http://www.pageantly.com/wp-content/uploads/3d.jpg]

In the first three images, the sphere was achieved using gradient feature.

- Draw Circle
- Gradient tool (G) (be sure to select the object)
- Click Gradient (right side pannel along with the swatch/layers)
- Select Radial in the selection
- Change the desired color (at least 2 colors)
- Click again the Gradient tool (G) to move the shadow or adjust the depth (you will see a control that you can play with after clicking this again)

For the fourth image from the left, follow the steps above (just change the color to blue and apply shadow: Effect > Stylize > Drop Shadow.
Just play the x-offset and y-offset, be sure to tick "preview" to see actual change.

Now for the 3D objects using other method:

- Select the object
- Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel
- Make sure to tick the "preview to see effect immediately"
- Set the position (for that image, I think that was "Front"
- You can play with it's depth, surface, and perspective (you can just drag the image in the dialog box using your mouse to position your object's perspective.